# Handling static application properties in AWS

Tags: aws-cloudformation

My applications are reading properties from a file on the system.
We update property files and upload to S3 and download the same during instance creation.

But when we use AWS CloudFormation there is not direct way to update S3 object.

Please suggest how DevOps manage the dynamic properties.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something that should probably be under the domain of your configuration management system.

I've had great success in separating the concept of infrastructure management and instance configuration.  Infrastructure management ( or infrastructure as code ) is handled exclusivly by AWS::CF, where as everything else ( instance/application configuration ) is handled by chef.

With this pattern I can explicitly control application and machine-level expectations, manage configuration files, and monitor application state independently of how the infrastructure is configured and managed.

It sounds like what you're trying to do is make AWS::CF do all of the work for all of the things without using a configuration management system.  That might work for awhile, but eventually you're going to hit problems like this ( and quite possibly other, more complicated problems down the road ) that require you to rethink your strategy.